# Display the user profile from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have already tried to make a login form and I also want to display the user login profile that I have stored in the database. However, I have no idea how to do it neither from the model nor the controller.

I have stored all the user information in the Customers table of my database.

This is the code of Customer model:

```
    public IList<Customer> GetProfileCustomer(string name)
    {
        var list_customer = from c in DataContext.Customers
                            where c.WebAccount == name
                            select c;
        return list_customer.ToList();
    }
```

And this my AccountController:

```
    public ActionResult ShowProfile()
    {
      return View();
    }
```

I want to get the result that I wrote in my model, to display in my view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the result of the function as ViewModel:

```
public ActionResult ShowProfile()
    {
      ViewData.Model = GetProfileCustomer("foo");
      return View();
    }
```

Then your view will declare `@model IList<Customer>` and you'll access properties simply like this:

```
@foreach (var customer in Model)
{
<p>@customer.FirstName</p>
}
```

Comment: when I used GetProfileCustomer() in my controller, it error , it doesn't contain in the current context. I ready import all the model in my controller.